# Visual Studio UML Modeling Projects - Version control and how to search the model?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, uml

Sorry for the bad title, and the somewhat different questions!

I have been searching the web and SO for these (trivial) question, but I seam to drown in MSDN pages (some are great!). The tool I'm used to for UML design is Enterprise Architecture, so my questions is kind of related to how EA works.

I have three questions:
(1) Version control and shared model for large projects. Is it possible the have the model in a shared database. Having it in TFS under source control seems like problems with people working in the same packages.

(2) How do I search the UML model in Visual Studio? I want to be able to find in what diagrams a specific class is used in and so on... How to query the model?

(3) In a sequence diagram is the messages just plain text. Can I connect them to an operation?

Thanks!

Cheers
--Jocke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sharing models in TFS, see [Managing Models and Graphs Under Version Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd574364).

If you use **CTRL+F** to search your solution, you should get a list of all the diagrams that have a specific element.

You can connect messages to operations on a class diagram, but you have to bind the lifeline to a type. This also makes the signature visible and lets you edit it:

Select the lifeline and press F4. In the **Properties** window, set the **Type** property to an existing type or enter a name for a new type. Right-click the message label. Choose **Create Operation**.

-or-

Right-click the lifeline. Choose **Create Class**.

See [UML Sequence Diagrams: Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409389#BasicSteps).